# Missing System Tray Icons in the Cinnamon Desktop Environment

Tags: icons, 17.10, cinnamon, system-tray

I am currently using the Cinnamon Desktop Environment in which I have applications which uses the System Tray but when these applications are opened, the icons are not shown in the system tray but notifications from the applications do appear.

Has anyone had this experience and are there any solutions?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Mint 18.2, Cinnamon 3.4.6.

Comment: I have the same issue with Cinnamon 3.8.8

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be late but I just had this problem so, I am gonna leave the way I solved it in case someone runs into the problem in future:

1. Open the terminal <kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
2. Run the following to bring up the Panel Editor:

```
/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/cinnamon-settings.py panel
```

3. From the panel editor, add a new panel on the panel and select where you would like it to be positioned.
4. Welcome back your panel :)

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280807/116985

> It was found that "System tray" applet was disabled in my system.
>
> Fixed in this way:
>
> - enter app menu type "Applets" and press "Enter" button
> - on "Installed Applets" tab search for "System tray" applet
> - select it and press "Add to panel" button
>
> some running applications might need to be restarted in order to appear in the tray

Comment: The thing is that the Applet is there but the icons of some apps are not being displayed.